# multiple if but only runs the first one? javascript

Tags: javascript

so I wrote this for my first computer science class assignment. However, the page returns that if input is `gpa(A)`, the results is `3`. It's like only the first conditionals `if` is running. I switched around the `A`, `B` ,`C` and `2`, `3`, `4` but it's always the first `if` no matter what the `gpa(r)` is. How does this happen?

```
    var gpa = function(r) {
        if (r = "B"){
            return 3;
        } 
        if (r = "C"){
            return 2;
        }
        if (r = "A"){
            return 4;
        }
     }
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, `===` is a comparison operator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to compare between two values you **should** use `==` or `===` and **not** `=` which assigns a value.

```
var gpa = function(r) {
    if (r == "B"){
        return 3;
    } 
    if (r == "C"){
        return 2;
    }
    if (r == "A"){
        return 4;
    }
 }
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) about the difference between `==` and `===`.

Comment: Even better, avoid using `==` and use `===`.

Comment: I think the word _"need"_ is too strong here, `>` and `<` are also comparison operators.